# Removing /tmp partition, what will happen?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

We have a CentOS 6.6 server running, which is using a Raid0 on SSDs for the `/tmp` mount point (used for fast i/o). These SSDs need to be removed from the server, so the device where `/tmp` is pointing won't exist anymore. Which reaction can I expect from CentOS, will there be a `/tmp` file?

How would you proceed with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will just use the `/tmp` directory on the `/` (root) partition, whilst the SSDs are unmounted.

The `/` partition, when created, will contain ALL of the necessary directories. Now, these directories are just used, as one would expect, until something is mounted "on top" of them, and thereafter the new mounted disks are then used to store the data.

The OS will still write to `/tmp`, it doesn't care where that data ends up, or on what device.

As an example:

> You install a new linux distro, with the entire FS on one partition.
>   You log on as `user`, and write things to your home directory,
>   `/home/user/`, for example a file called `test.txt`.
>
> Now log out. Log in as `root`, and mount a previously formatted disk on
>   `/tmp`. Copy over the `/home` directory to `/tmp` so you end up with
>   `/tmp/home`. Unmount it from `/tmp/` and remount on `/home`. Log out
>   the `root` user
>
> Now log back in as `user`. Make some changes to the
>   `/home/user/test.txt` file and save. Log out.
>
> Now as `root`, unmount the `/home` drive. Log out `root`.
>
> Log back in as `user` and open `/home/user/test.txt`. You will see the
>   unedited version of the file.

---

### TL;DR

So, in brief, a directory is always there, just what it points to changes, when things are mounted on it.